# Reusing objects app mobile

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a mobile application in as3. I'm optimizing.
I have a scroll containing 30 objects (buttons). All buttons are the same except its title.
This bucle is inside the container scroll:

```
for(var a:int=0; a<global.get_A.get_B.length; a++)
{
    b = new ItemList(global.get_A.get_B[a]);
    b.y = this.height;
    addChild(b);
    b.mouseChildren = false;
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ffe.html talking about the reusing objects, but not for interactive objects. 
Is it possible?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking here could you clarify it. When you use the NEW operator you are creating a new object and not reusing the old one. Basically, "NEW" detatches the current object from the var("b").The code you posted should work as( I think ) you are intending. The only problem you will have is how to reference the buttons on an event like click.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse them if they need to be visible at the same time. Besides, if you're only creating them once (on init) there should be little performance benefit of reusing them. Just make sure you remove them from the display list when they are outside of the visible scroll area, which should improve performance at least a little.